# Tool to combine line segments into a polygon in powerpoint?

Tags: powerpoint, line, polygon

Is there a tool in powerpoint 2010 to combine lines into a polygon?

In [this answer](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24924605/connect-seperate-line-shapes-in-powerpoint-to-create-a-single-line-shape-not-a-group.html) I found that there was no way to do this (without VBA) in 2009, but is there a tool that can do this in the 2010 version that can do this for lines?

[*Example figure; I want the area in the middle to be a separate polygon.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8AT7.png)

Answer (score 0):

In PPT 2013 and onward (and possibly 2010 if you customize the toolbar) there are various merge shape commands, but they only work on closed shapes, not lines.  You may have to use the polygon tool to trace the shape you're after.

Comment: Yes, 
this is what I eventually did.

Comment: Luckily my shapes weren't too big. In powerpoint 2010 the shape commands can be accessed via [File][Options][Quick Access Toolbar][Commands not in the ribbon]. The box to show the quick access toolbar on the ribbon should be checked.